# tabs need to click twice to change the tab to the active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, bootstrap-tabs

I had a problem about the active tab.I use .append() to built tabs and I don't use href to connect data of tab.
when I click tab .console log() to show the text of the active tab.
My problem is when I clicked tab 2 the text of the active tab still is tab 1.
 
I have to clicked tab 2 again the active tab gonna change to tab 2.
I don't see anyone who has the same problem so wish someone can help me.
Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container">
          <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          </ul>
        </div>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            for(i = 1;i <= 2 ; i++){
              renewid='tab_'+i;
              if(i == 1){
                $('.nav-tabs').append("<li class='active'><a data-toggle='tab' id=" + renewid + ">Chart"+ [i] +"</a></li>");
              }
              else{
                $('.nav-tabs').append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' id=" + renewid + ">Chart"+ [i] +"</a></li>");
              }
            };
            $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
                alert('set_active = ' + $('.nav-tabs .active').text());
            });
        });
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `shown.bs.tab` event instead of `click`.

```
$(".nav-tabs a").on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    alert('set_active = ' + $('.nav-tabs .active').text());
});
```

Comment: wow,it can run successfully.Thanks!!Could U explain why should change the method to me?

Comment: @YuJingYu Refer to this to understand the events available for bootstrap tab. You just need to change the event type and your existing code will work fine. `https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp`

Answer (score -1):

You just need to apply 'addClass' method at the time of click event,that you can see in below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            
            for(i = 1;i <= 2 ; i++){
              renewid='tab_'+i;
              if(i == 1){
                $('.nav-tabs').append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' id=" + renewid + ">Chart"+ [i] +"</a></li>");
              }
              else{
                $('.nav-tabs').append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' id=" + renewid + ">Chart"+ [i] +"</a></li>");
              }
            };
            $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
            $('.nav-tabs').find('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active')
                alert('set_active = ' + $('.nav-tabs .active').text());
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Oh,it works.could U explain me why does this issue happened?

Comment: Because at the time of append the li tag you just declared the 'active' class by-default that was wrong as per your requirement, 

so you need to add that 'active' class when you click on particular li, so it only add 'active' class for that current li only. @YuJingYu